# Node/Express server CORS issue with a different server port

Tags: express, server, graphql

I have a node/graphql server running on sitename.com:3333
I've created another server that I'm running on sitename.com:3334

I'm able to make requests to the server at sitename.com:3333 from sitename.com as well as subdomain.sitename.com

But if I try to connect to sitename.com:3334 (just a different port) from subdomain.sitename.com it gives me a cors error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://sitename.com:3334/graphql. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

I've opened the ports in the firewall and setup ssl on the server and client.

Please help!

Client code is below:

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { withClientState } from 'apollo-link-state'
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { Agent } from 'https'
import fs from 'fs'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context'
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error'
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link'
import decode from 'jwt-decode'
import history from '../history'
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie'
import {
APP,
AUTH,
CLIENT_AUTH_REQUEST_TYPE,
CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD,
JWT,
VERSION
} from '../environment'
import https from 'https'
import { defaults, resolvers } from '../api'
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client'

const { CONSTANTS: { UNAUTHORIZED, FORBIDDEN } = {} } = APP
const cookies = new Cookies()

const opts = {
credentials: 'same-origin',
headers: {
'frontend-version': VERSION,
[AUTH.STRATEGIES.CLIENT.AUTH_HEADER]: CLIENT_AUTH_REQUEST_TYPE
}
}

const useLocalStorage = CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD.LOCAL_STORAGE
process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0

// const apolloCache = new InMemoryCache();

const apolloCache = new InMemoryCache({
// dataIdFromObject: e => `${e.__typename}_${e.id}` || null // eslint- 
disable-line no-underscore-dangle
})

// const watchedMutationLink = new WatchedMutationLink(apolloCache, 
watchedMutations);
const stateLink = withClientState({
cache: apolloCache,
defaults,
resolvers
})

const uploadLink = createUploadLink({
// uri: 'http://localhost:3333/graphql',
uri: 'https://demo.MYSITE.in:3334/graphql',

fetchOptions: {
agent: new https.Agent()
}
})

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
uri: 'https://demo.MYSITE.in:3334/graphql',

...opts
})

const TOKEN_NAME = 'x-connector-token'

const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
operation.setContext(({ headers = {} }) => {
const token = cookies.get('token')

if (token) {
  headers = { ...headers, 'x-connector-token': token }
}

return { headers }
})

return forward(operation)
})

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
if (graphQLErrors && graphQLErrors.filter(e => e).length > 0) {
graphQLErrors.map(({ message = '', status = 200 }) => {
  if (UNAUTHORIZED === message || status === 401) {
    if (
      history &&
      history.location &&
      history.location.pathname !== '/login'
    ) {
      history.push('/login')
    }
  }
  if (FORBIDDEN === message || status === 403) {
    history.push(`/error-page/403`)
  }
  return null
})
}
if (networkError && networkError.statusCode === 401) {
// eslint-disable-next-line
history.push('/login')
}
if (networkError && networkError.statusCode === 403) {
// Do something
}
if (networkError && networkError.statusCode === 400) {
// Do something
}
if (networkError && networkError.statusCode >= 500) {
// eslint-disable-next-line

history.push(`/error-page/${networkError.statusCode}`)
}
})

let links = [errorLink, stateLink, httpLink]

links = [
errorLink,
stateLink,
// afterwareLink,
// authMiddlewareLink,
authLink,
// watchedMutationLink,
// httpLink,
uploadLink
]

const link = ApolloLink.from(links)


export default new ApolloClient({
link,
cache: apolloCache,
connectToDevTools: true,
// opts: {
//   agent
// },
fetchOptions: {
agent: new https.Agent()
// rejectUnauthorized: false
},
defaultOptions: {
query: {
  errorPolicy: 'all'
}
},

onError: ({ networkError, graphQLErrors }) => {}
})
```

Server Code:

```
const app = express();

// tried this too
const corsOptions = {
origin: 'https://demo.MYSITE.in',
}
// also tried app.use(cors)
app.use(cors({
'allowedHeaders': ['Content-Type'],
'origin': '*',
'preflightContinue': true
}));

app.use(helmet());
// app.use(cors());
```

Comment: forgot to mention, the clients are node/express app builds installed on nginx

Answer (score -1):

The browser will not make requests to a server of different origin than the origin that the web page itself came from (and a different port constitutes a different origin) unless you specifically enable that request for that new origin on your server.  This is a garden variety CORs issue of which there are millions of posts and articles on how to handle.  Since you show NONE of your code in your question, we can't recommend a specific code fix to your code.

Your server needs to support the specific CORS request you are trying to do.  If you're using Express, then the [CORS module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) does a lot of the work for you if properly implemented.  CORS is there for your site's protection so Javascript in other people's web pages run from a browser can't arbitrarily use your APIs so be careful in exactly what you open up to CORS requests.

And, since this seems like a new issue to you, I would strongly suggest you read and learn about [what CORs is and how it works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Also, note that there are "Simple" CORS requests and "Pre-flighted Requests" (non-simple requests) and more work is required to enable Pre-flighted requests.  The browser decides whether a given cross origin request is simple or requires pre-flight based on the exact parameters of the request and your server has to do more things to enable pre-flighted requests.

Comment: The client page runs on nginx, the server on port 3333. the server doesn't serve the page, it's served by nginx

Comment: @rainmaker - I'm not sure what that comment means.  The point is that you're trying to make a Javascript request to a different port than where the page comes from so that make it cross origin.  So, the server will need specific cross origin support for that specific type of request before the browser will allow it.  Have you read anything about how CORs restrictions are enforced and how to enable CORs access?  This is all pretty vanilla stuff covered in thousands of posts and articles.  I've answered multiple questions on this very topic today alone on stackoverflow.

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear. The server that runs on port 3333 is a graphql server. It doesn't serve any pages. The client application is separate and runs on nginx installed on the same box. I've read through the cors doc, not able to find a solution yet.

Comment: Well, the graphql server has to enable CORs.

Comment: I've tried that and many other options... no success! const app = express();

//CORS middleware
const allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'demo.MYSITE.in');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    next();
}


app.use(helmet());

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://demo.MYSITE.in'
  
}

//app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(cors);

app.use(morgan('dev'));

Comment: @rainmaker - Multiline code is not readable in comments.  Please add it to the end of your question and format it appropriately.  Also, you can look in the network tab of the browser debugger and see exactly what is happening with your request that doesn't succeed.  That should show where the issue is.  Probably your CORS code is not configured properly.

Comment: @rainmaker - Also, certain types of requests require extra code for CORs.  So, please show the client-side code for a specific request that is being blocked.

Comment: added the apollo client code for reference. The call is a made via a regular apollo mutation.